# Delete from sql statement

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which is supposed to delete a post from a database, however when the query is executed it does not delete anything. This is the query string.

`$query = "DELETE post FROM kaoscraft_posts WHERE post_id = $postid"`

What is wrong with the statement?

Yes, all variables are set and yes I have tested with an exact `post_id`

If you need more information, please just comment and tell me, don't be rude about it.

Comment: But being rude is what SO is best at!

Comment: @Strawberry Half the people that answer questions are rude.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the MySQL manual:

> For the single-table syntax, the DELETE statement deletes rows from tbl_name and returns a count of the number of deleted rows.

So you can't delete the `post` only, you need to delete whole row.

```
$query = "DELETE FROM kaoscraft_posts WHERE post_id = $postid"
```

If you want to clear the `post` only, you can do it by `UPDATE` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Delete query structure should be like this:

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE condition ;
```

You can not delete a column value in your table. you need to delete whole record of a row. If you wanted to delete single row then you need to update this row.

try this:

```
 $query = "DELETE  FROM kaoscraft_posts WHERE post_id = $postid";
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra 'word' in your statement...  it should be

```
$query = "DELETE FROM kaoscraft_posts WHERE post_id = $postid"
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look on the below syntax,you come to know your mistake

```
DELETE FROM table_name WHERE column_name = some_value;
```